# iOS Query via Album MPMediaEntityPersistentID sometimes brings back no songs

Tags: ios, swift, mpmediaquery

I'm writing an app that plays music using Apple's built in MediaPlayer library. I store an array of albums and an array of Ids, and then when one is selected I search for an album using the id. For some reason, some of the albums can't find any songs despite having an id associated with them. It is the same albums each time that won't work, and there seems to be no pattern to this.

I use the following code to store the names and ids into two arrays

```
let query = MPMediaQuery.albumsQuery()
let mediaCollection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: query.items!)

for album in mediaCollection.items {
            albumTitleArray.append(album.albumTitle!)
            albumIdArray.append(album.albumPersistentID)
        }
```

When one is selected, I then pass the id to the queryMedia method

```
func queryMedia(identifier:MPMediaEntityPersistentID) -> MPMediaItemCollection {

    let predicateId = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: String(identifier), forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID, comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparison.EqualTo)

    let query = MPMediaQuery.init()
    query.addFilterPredicate(predicateId)

    let collection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: query.items!)

    return collection;
}
```

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must have been some characters being malformed, or a comparison error in the query caused by the conversion from MPMediaEntityPersistentID to String.

I've changed the code to instead convert to a NSNumber and the query now finds all albums correctly.

change this part in code example above

```
String(identifier)
```

to

```
NSNumber(unsignedLongLong: identifier)
```

so it looks like this

```
func queryMedia(identifier:MPMediaEntityPersistentID) -> MPMediaItemCollection {

let predicateId = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: NSNumber(unsignedLongLong: identifier), forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID, comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparison.EqualTo)

let query = MPMediaQuery.init()
query.addFilterPredicate(predicateId)

let collection = MPMediaItemCollection(items: query.items!)

return collection;
}
```

Comment: This is an old post, but we struggled with a similar issue. For us it was caused by the PersistentID (which is an unsigned Int64, or Unsigned long long) being incorrectly converted in various tools. Likely what was happening in your case was the String was converting it as a signed value, giving the wrong result. I think you are on the right track to force it to be unsignedLongLong. You need to be careful with this everywhere when using the PersistentID.

Answer (score 0):

I am using XCode 13.1 and iOS 14.8 at the moment and this is still an issue.

I need to wrap the persistentId with `NSNumber(value: persistentId)` for this to work correctly.

But I also discovered that if I first created a query using `MPMediaQuery.songs()` then I did not have to use `NSNumber()`

```
func LoadMediaLibraryTrackData(_ track: inout AudioZoomTrack, _ persistentId:MPMediaEntityPersistentID) {
        
  /// Works
  let trackFilter = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: NSNumber(value: persistentId), forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID)
  let query = MPMediaQuery(filterPredicates: [trackFilter])

  /// Fails
  let trackFilter = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: persistentId, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID)
  let query = MPMediaQuery(filterPredicates: [trackFilter])

  /// Works
  let query = MPMediaQuery.songs()
  let trackFilter = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: persistentId, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID)     
  query.addFilterPredicate(trackFilter)

  ...
}
```